# Paper Cut on TM T70II Epson Thermal Printer (ePOS) from Javascript (Android Hybrid app)

Tags: javascript, android, printing, epos

I don't know where I am doing wrong but I cannot get the paper cut (partial or full). Im using the following javascript code in my hybrid android app and printing a receipt on EPOS.

```
 var _EscCommand = (function () {
function _EscCommand() {
    this.ESC = "\u001B";
    this.GS = "\u001D";
    this.InitializePrinter = this.ESC + "@";
    this.BoldOn = this.ESC + "E" + "\u0001";
    this.BoldOff = this.ESC + "E" + "\0";
    this.DoubleHeight = this.GS + "!" + "\u0001";
    this.DoubleWidth = this.GS + "!" + "\u0010";
    this.DoubleOn = this.GS + "!" + "\u0011"; // 2x sized text (double-high + double-wide)
    this.DoubleOff = this.GS + "!" + "\0";
    this.PrintAndFeedMaxLine = this.ESC + "J" + "\u00FF";
    this.TextAlignLeft = this.ESC + "a" + "0";
    this.TextAlignCenter = this.ESC + "a" + "1";
    this.TextAlignRight = this.ESC + "a" + "2";
    this.PartialPaperCut = this.GS+"V"+"\0";
    this.FullPaperCut = this.GS+"V"+"\1";
}
_EscCommand.prototype.PrintAndFeedLine = function (verticalUnit) {
    if (verticalUnit > 255)
        verticalUnit = 255;
    if (verticalUnit < 0)
        verticalUnit = 0;
    return this.ESC + "J" + String.fromCharCode(verticalUnit);
};
_EscCommand.prototype.CutAndFeedLine = function (verticalUnit) {
    if (verticalUnit === void 0) {
        return this.ESC + "V" + 1;
    }
    if (verticalUnit > 255)
        verticalUnit = 255;
    if (verticalUnit < 0)
        verticalUnit = 0;
    return this.ESC + "V" + String.fromCharCode(verticalUnit);
};
return _EscCommand;
```

} ());

Im using this         this.PartialPaperCut = this.GS+"V"+"\0"; line as well as a method I copied from Internet and I don't get the cutter to cut the paper.
Any help is highly appreciated..

Javascript line where I build the print string:
print_dtl += Esc.InitializePrinter+Esc.DoubleOn+"   kitchen COPY\n\n" + Esc.DoubleOff +kit_dtl + kit_copy +"\n\n\n\n"+Esc.PrintAndFeedMaxLine + Esc.CutAndFeedLine();
I could print all except the paper cut at the end. Hope it clarifies the commentor below

Comment: None of the code you've included makes any effort to send anything to the printer. How are we supposed to tell you why it isn't working when you don't include that code?

Comment: Sorry, The printer actually prints everything except the paper cut.. I didn't put the whole script here..

Comment: print_dtl += Esc.InitializePrinter+Esc.DoubleOn+"   kitchen COPY\n\n" + Esc.DoubleOff +kit_dtl + kit_copy +"\n\n\n\n"+Esc.PrintAndFeedMaxLine + Esc.CutAndFeedLine();